# Index array error

Tags: sql, arrays, vb.net

I have a website that displays charts based on stats from a database. However, I get this error "**Index was outside the bounds of the array.**" and points to this code:

```
>Line 1462: ctrAPM(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
```

Here's my whole Sub:

```vb
Public Function Bar_Task_Cat() As String
    Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MSSQLstring)
    Conn.Open()

    Dim strUserCode = CType(Session("usrCd"), String)

    Dim SQLstring As String

    If strUserCode = "ADMIN" Then
        SQLstring = "SELECT COUNT(AskAOID) AS credits, CatCode AS category, ProductCode " _
                                & "FROM dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN '" & dpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString & "' AND '" & dpTo.SelectedDate.ToString & "') " _
                                & "AND (Status='ACTIVE' OR Status='CLOSED') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) AND (CatCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ProductCode IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY ProductCode, CatCode " _
                                & "ORDER BY CatCode"
    Else
        SQLstring = "SELECT COUNT(AskAOID) AS credits, CatCode AS category, ProductCode " _
                                & "FROM dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN '" & dpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString & "' AND '" & dpTo.SelectedDate.ToString & "') " _
                                & "AND (Status='ACTIVE' OR Status='CLOSED') " _
                                & "AND (Deferred = '" & strUserCode & "') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) AND (CatCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ProductCode IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY ProductCode, CatCode " _
                                & "ORDER BY CatCode"
    End If

    Dim SQLcmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLstring, Conn)
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dpFrom.SelectedDate)
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dpTo.SelectedDate) '& "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo) " 
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(SQLstring, Conn)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS)

    Conn.Close()

    Dim Def_Color_t(12) As String
    Def_Color_t(0) = "AFD8F8"
    Def_Color_t(1) = "F6BD0F"
    Def_Color_t(2) = "8BBA00"
    Def_Color_t(3) = "FF8E46"
    Def_Color_t(4) = "008E8E"
    Def_Color_t(5) = "D64646"
    Def_Color_t(6) = "8E468E"
    Def_Color_t(7) = "588526"
    Def_Color_t(8) = "B3AA00"
    Def_Color_t(9) = "008ED6"
    Def_Color_t(10) = "9D080D"
    Def_Color_t(11) = "A186BE"
    Def_Color_t(12) = "AFD8F8"


    Dim ctr As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrD As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrM As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrF As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrA As Integer = 0
    Dim ctrO As Integer = 0
    Dim m_ctr As Integer = 0
    Dim m1_ctr As Integer = 0

    Dim strXML As String
    Dim Cat As String
    Dim OldCat As String
    Dim strCatName As String

    Dim ProdCode As String

    'counters for Products
    Dim ctrAPM(26), ctrDMX(26), ctrDVS(26), ctrDVX(26), ctrEAM(26), ctrEPR(26), ctrFCX(26), ctrMHM(26), ctrONL(26), ctrOTH(26), ctrPOR(26), ctrUFF(26), ctrXMT(26) As String

    'counters for Categories
    Dim ctrAR(13), ctrDA(13), ctrDB(13), ctrDC(13), ctrDD(13), ctrDE(13), ctrDF(13), ctrDG(13), ctrDH(13), ctrDI(13), ctrDJ(13), ctrDK(13), ctrDL(13) As String
    Dim ctrDM(13), ctrDN(13), ctrDO(13), ctrDP(13), ctrDQ(13), ctrFW(13), ctrOL(13), ctrOO(13), ctrPM(13), ctrPQ(13), ctrPR(13), ctrSS(13), ctrST(13) As String

    strXML = ""
    Cat = ""
    OldCat = ""
    strCatName = ""

    strXML = strXML & "<chart palette='2' labelDisplay='Rotate' slantLabels='1' showBorder='0' bgColor='FFFFFF,FFFFFF' showPercentValues='1' showPercentInToolTip='1' stack100Percent='1' caption='Percentage of Tasks by Category by Product' shownames='1' showvalues='0' showSum='1' decimals='0' useRoundEdges='1'>"
    strXML = strXML & "<categories>"
    Do Until ctr = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        Cat = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("category").ToString
        If Cat <> OldCat Then
            Select Case DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("category").ToString
                Case "AR"
                    strCatName = "AR" 'Architecture and Application
                Case "DA"
                    strCatName = "DA" 'Accessories
                Case "DB"
                    strCatName = "DB" 'Advanced Control
                Case "DC"
                    strCatName = "DC" 'Batch
                Case "DD"
                    strCatName = "DD" 'Bundles
                Case "DE"
                    strCatName = "DE" 'Engineering Tools
                Case "DF"
                    strCatName = "DF" 'Modernization and Migration
                Case "DG"
                    strCatName = "DG" 'DeltaV SIS
                Case "DH"
                    strCatName = "DH" 'Wireless
                Case "DI"
                    strCatName = "DI" 'DeltaV Hardware
                Case "DJ"
                    strCatName = "DJ" 'DeltaV Zones
                Case "DK"
                    strCatName = "DK" 'Integration and Connectivity
                Case "DL"
                    strCatName = "DL" 'Languages
                Case "DM"
                    strCatName = "DM" 'Cactus
                Case "DN"
                    strCatName = "DN" 'Operations Software
                Case "DO"
                    strCatName = "DO" 'PROVOX and RS3 Transitions
                Case "DP"
                    strCatName = "DP" 'Workstation Hardware and Software
                Case "DQ"
                    strCatName = "DQ" 'Simulate and Virtualization
                Case "FW"
                    strCatName = "FW" 'Forward to other groups
                Case "OL"
                    strCatName = "OL" 'Ordering, Licensing, Policies
                Case "OO"
                    strCatName = "OO" 'Others
                Case "PM"
                    strCatName = "PM" 'Forward to Product Manager
                Case "PQ"
                    strCatName = "PQ" 'Proposals and Quotations
                Case "PR"
                    strCatName = "PR" 'Product Information
                Case "SS"
                    strCatName = "SS" 'Forward to Sales Support
                Case "ST"
                    strCatName = "ST" 'Systems and Tools
            End Select
            strXML = strXML & "<category label='" & strCatName & "' value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            m_ctr = m_ctr + 1
        End If
        OldCat = Cat
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</categories>"

    'initialize
    ctr = 0

    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        ctrAPM(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrDMX(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrDVS(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrDVX(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrEAM(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrEPR(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrFCX(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrMHM(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrONL(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrOTH(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrPOR(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrUFF(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctrXMT(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop

    ctr = 0
    Cat = ""
    OldCat = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("category").ToString

    Do Until ctr = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        ProdCode = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("ProductCode").ToString

        Cat = DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("category").ToString

        If Cat <> OldCat Then
            m1_ctr = m1_ctr + 1
        End If

        Select Case ProdCode
            Case "APM"
                ctrAPM(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "DMX"
                ctrDMX(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "DVS"
                ctrDVS(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "DVX"
                ctrDVX(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "EAM"
                ctrEAM(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "EPR"
                ctrEPR(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "FCX"
                ctrFCX(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "MHM"
                ctrMHM(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "ONL"
                ctrONL(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "OTH"
                ctrOTH(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "POR"
                ctrPOR(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "UFF"
                ctrUFF(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
            Case "XMT"
                ctrXMT(m1_ctr) = "<set value='" & DS.Tables(0).Rows(ctr)("credits").ToString & "' />"
        End Select

        OldCat = Cat

        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Asset Portal' color='8E468E' showValues='0'>" 'Asset Portal
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrAPM(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='AMS Device' color='F6BD0F' showValues='0'>" 'AMS Device
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrDMX(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='DeltaV SIS' color='607416' showValues='0'>" 'DeltaV SIS
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrDVS(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='DeltaV' color='588526' showValues='0'>" 'DeltaV
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrDVX(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Essential Asset Monitoring' color='A3CC77' showValues='0'>" 'Essential Asset Monitoring
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrEAM(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='EPRO' color='B3AA00' showValues='0'>" 'EPRO
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrEPR(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Field Communicator' color='8BBA00' showValues='0'>" 'Field Communicator
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrFCX(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Machinery Health' color='FF8E46' showValues='0'>" 'Machinery Health
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrMHM(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Online' color='D64646' showValues='0'>" 'Online
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrONL(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Others' color='9D080D' showValues='0'>" 'Others
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrOTH(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='Portables' color='008E8E' showValues='0'>" 'Portables
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrPOR(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='USB Fieldbus Interface' color='AA9CB6' showValues='0'>" 'USB Fieldbus Interface
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrUFF(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    ctr = 0
    strXML = strXML & "<dataset seriesName='9420 Wireless Vibration Transmitter' color='008ED6' showValues='0'>" '9420 Wireless Vibration Transmitter
    Do Until ctr = m_ctr
        strXML = strXML & ctrXMT(ctr)
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop
    strXML = strXML & "</dataset>"

    strXML = strXML & "</chart>"

    'Create the chart - Column 3D Chart with data from strXML variable using dataXML method
    Return RenderChartHTML("Charts/NewCharts/StackedColumn3D.swf", "", strXML, "myNext", "450", "500", False)
    'for gauge
End Function
```

But the problem I have is that I encounter the error only when an admin is accessing the site (i.e. `strUserCode = "ADMIN"`). Non-admin accounts work just fine. I can't figure out what went wrong, but what I know is that it was working fine like a month ago :(

Answer (score 0):

i guess your query is returning more than 26 categories when logged in as Admin. Since you said it was working a month ago, this looks like the possible scenario.

```
Case Else
     strCatName = "Others" 'Unknown category
```

might help you debug it better.
The other option is to run the SQL query with Admin directly and check you are not getting any unexpected categories.

Comment: Hi, sorry I meant ctrAPM(ctr) = "<set value='0' />"